# Pandas create a new column based on exact match of text values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, merge

I have two dataframes that look like below

```
proj_df = pd.DataFrame({'reg_id':[1,2,3,4],
                        'part_no':['P1','P2','P3','P4'],
                        'partner':['A','B','C','D'],
                        'cust_name_1': ['ABC PVT LTD','Tesla','Apple','Google'],
                        'cust_name_2':['ABC','Tesla Ltd','Apple Inc','Google Enterprises'],
                        'cust_name_3':['ABC','Tesla America','Apple America','Google Ent Pvt ltd']})


data_df = pd.DataFrame({'cust_name': ['ABC','Tesla America','Apple Inc','Google','Google','ABC'],
                        'partner':['A','B','C','D','E','A'],
                        'part_no':['P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P6'],
                        'qty':[100,100,600,150,320,410]})
```

I would like to do the below

a) Identify the exactly matching customer name column from `proj_df` by comparing it with `data_df`.

b) Ex: select one exactly matching column from `cust_name_1`, `cust_name_2`, `cust_name_3` by comparing it with `cust_name` column from data_df. If two or more columns has 100% match, then choose any one of the columns.

b) Compare/merge both dataframes based on matching `part_no`, `partner` columns.

I tried the below but it is going nowhere

```
unique_names = data_df['cust_name'].tolist()
for name in unique_names:
    proj_df['similarity_ratio'] = proj_df.apply(lambda x: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, name, x.name_1).ratio(), axis=1)
```

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need 100% match use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with left join, then compare both columns for exact match and for one row per `part_no/partner` add [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = (proj_df.melt(['reg_id','part_no','partner'],
                  var_name='matching_column_name', 
                  value_name='matching_column_value')
             .merge(data_df, on=['part_no','partner']))

df = (df[df['matching_column_value'].eq(df['cust_name'])]
           .drop_duplicates(['part_no','partner']))
```

Last for matching by original `proj_df` use left join only by necesary columns:

```
need = ['part_no','partner', 'matching_column_name','matching_column_value','qty']

df = proj_df.merge(df[need], how='left')
print (df)
   reg_id part_no partner  cust_name_1         cust_name_2  \
0       1      P1       A  ABC PVT LTD                 ABC   
1       2      P2       B        Tesla           Tesla Ltd   
2       3      P3       C        Apple           Apple Inc   
3       4      P4       D       Google  Google Enterprises   

          cust_name_3 matching_column_name matching_column_value  qty  
0                 ABC          cust_name_2                   ABC  100  
1       Tesla America          cust_name_3         Tesla America  100  
2       Apple America          cust_name_2             Apple Inc  600  
3  Google Ent Pvt ltd          cust_name_1                Google  150
```

If need maximal similar match solution use `SequenceMatcher` for `ratio` and for first maximal `ratio` rows use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
df = (proj_df.melt(['reg_id','part_no','partner'], 
                   var_name='matching_column_name', 
                   value_name='matching_column_value')
              .merge(data_df, on=['part_no','partner'])
df['similarity_ratio'] = [difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio() 
                           for a, b in zip(df['matching_column_value'], df['cust_name'])]

df = df.loc[df.groupby(['part_no','partner'])['similarity_ratio'].idxmax()]
print (df)

need = ['part_no','partner', 'matching_column_name','matching_column_value','qty']

df = proj_df.merge(df[need], how='left')
print (df)
   reg_id part_no partner  cust_name_1         cust_name_2  \
0       1      P1       A  ABC PVT LTD                 ABC   
1       2      P2       B        Tesla           Tesla Ltd   
2       3      P3       C        Apple           Apple Inc   
3       4      P4       D       Google  Google Enterprises   

          cust_name_3 matching_column_name matching_column_value  qty  
0                 ABC          cust_name_2                   ABC  100  
1       Tesla America          cust_name_3         Tesla America  100  
2       Apple America          cust_name_2             Apple Inc  600  
3  Google Ent Pvt ltd          cust_name_1                Google  150
```

Comment: wow. you are fast and accurate than a AI solution.

Comment: @TheGreat - Do you need exact 100% match or `SequenceMatcher` solution with maximal similar match?

Comment: Is this something that you can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76071012/pandas-dynamic-date-filter-and-compute-3-new-columns-based-on-past

Comment: @TheGreat - I test it and first merge working well for you? Because if match by `cust_name` only get many duplicated rows.

Comment: Yes I don't think it will be duplicate. while most of the columns values might be same but if you pay attention, you will notice that date values will be different for each row (and there will be 4 rows for each transaction because of 4 projects in our sample data). I don't know how else to do this. Any help please?

Comment: I updated the expected output in other post. we need to do this for each customer though. sample data has only customer which is `ABC` but in real life, the output has to be each customer and we link it to the proj_df

Comment: @TheGreat - Sorry, I have no time for solve your question :(