# pandas dynamic date filter and compute 3 new columns based on past

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, group-by

I have two dataframes that looks like below

```
 transaction_df = pd.DataFrame({'cust_name': ['ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC'],
                        'partner':['A','A','A','B','C','C'],
                        'part_no':['P1','P2','P1','P2','P3','P3'],
                        'transaction_date':['21/05/2021','21/05/2022','21/01/2023','21/09/2020','11/05/2022','18/05/2022'],
                        'qty':[100,100,600,150,320,410]})
transaction_df['transaction_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df['transaction_date'])

# Create proj_df
proj_df = pd.DataFrame({'proj_id':[1,2,3,4],
                        'part_no':['P1','P2','P3','P4'],
                        'partner':['A','A','F','C'],
                        'last_purchase_date':['11/07/2022','19/09/2021','20/04/2023','27/09/2020'],
                        'cust_name': ['ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC']})
proj_df['last_purchase_date'] = pd.to_datetime(proj_df['last_purchase_date'])
```

My objective is to do the below

a) Create 3 new columns in proj_df - `cust_total_trans`, `cust_part_total_trans` and `cust_part_partner_total_trans`

Each of this column is computed based on the below logic

`cust_total_trans` - Compute total number of transactions for each of the customer before the last_purchase_date provided in the proj_df for each proj_id

`cust_part_total_trans` - Compute total number of transactions for each of the customer and part combination before the last_purchase_date provided in the proj_df for each proj_id

`cust_part_partner_total_trans` - Compute total number of transactions for each of the customer, part and partner combination before the last_purchase_date provided in the proj_df for each proj_id

So, I tried the below

```
merged_df = transaction_df.merge(proj_df, on="cust_name")

last_purchase_dates = merged_df.groupby("proj_id")["last_purchase_date"].max()

# Compute cust_total_transactions
cust_total_trans = merged_df.groupby("cust_name").size().reset_index(name="cust_total_trans")

# Compute cust_part_total_trans
cust_part_total_trans = merged_df.groupby(["cust_name", "part_no_x"]).size().reset_index(name="cust_part_total_trans")

# Compute cust_part_partner_total_trans
cust_part_partner_total_trans = merged_df.groupby(["cust_name", "part_no_x", "partner_x"]).size().reset_index(name="cust_part_partner_total_trans")
```

but this doesn't help me get the expected output. How do I apply the `before last purchase date` criteria. Meaning, I need to count only if they are before the last purchase date of the project.

I expect my output to be like as below. sorted in ascending order of dates column. My real transaction data is a big data with 100K rows and project data is 10K rows. So, any efficient and elegant solution is helpful

[image]

Comment: Your minimal example has some issues: `data_df` is not defined (I expect it should be `transaction_df['transaction_date']` instead ?). You also write about doing things per customer but you only have one customer in both dataframes

Comment: yes, I thought doing it for one customer, I can replicate it for other customers. Just groupby. When you groupby now, you will have only one group because one customer but in real life tere will be more customers. So, code will not change. fixed the typo

Comment: You also didn't mention that each transaction is only attributed to a single project. It appears that each project begin on the previous project's `last_purchase_date` and ends at that project's `last_purchase_date`. Is that correct? Because with the way you phrased your question `cust_total_trans` would have values `5,2,6,1` for projects `1,2,3,4`. Please edit your question/expected output accordingly.

Also, there's an inconsistency for `last_purchase_date` for `proj_id=1`. The month and day have been swapped between the dataframe's definition and the value in the expected output

Comment: no. project and transactions doesn't have any logic like it is only to single project. my sample data is random. So, there is no such logic. The connection is only based on 3 variables such as Cust_name, part_no and partner. a project could have >=1 transactions.  And no more assumptions like what you say about the project start and end date. Those are random as well. So, you need not worry about that. I will check the output again. but hope this clarifies the problem statement

Comment: @rorshan - I updated the expected output. hope this helps. Any input is appreciated

Comment: It's like we compute those 3 columns/features for every row of proj_df because each project has different last purchase date. So, for each project we need to compute those 3 column values. not sure whether for loop is an efficient and elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

transaction_df = pd.DataFrame({'cust_name': ['ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC'],
                        'partner':['A','A','A','B','C','C'],
                        'part_no':['P1','P2','P1','P2','P3','P3'],
                        'transaction_date':['21/05/2021','21/05/2022','21/01/2023','21/09/2020','11/05/2022','18/05/2022'],
                        'qty':[100,100,600,150,320,410]})
transaction_df['transaction_date'] = pd.to_datetime(transaction_df['transaction_date'], dayfirst=True)

# Create proj_df
proj_df = pd.DataFrame({'proj_id':[1,2,3,4],
                        'part_no':['P1','P2','P3','P4'],
                        'partner':['A','A','F','C'],
                        'last_purchase_date':['11/07/2022','19/09/2021','20/04/2023','27/09/2020'],
                        'cust_name': ['ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC']})
proj_df['last_purchase_date'] = pd.to_datetime(proj_df['last_purchase_date'], dayfirst=True)


merge = pd.merge(proj_df, transaction_df, on='cust_name')
merge = merge[merge['last_purchase_date']>=merge['transaction_date']]
#setting index is necessary for value_counts() to match correctly
proj_df = proj_df.set_index('proj_id')
proj_df['cust_total_trans'] = merge['proj_id'].value_counts()

proj_df = proj_df.reset_index()
merge = pd.merge(proj_df, transaction_df, on=['cust_name', 'part_no'])
merge = merge[merge['last_purchase_date']>=merge['transaction_date']]
#setting index is necessary for value_counts() to match correctly
proj_df = proj_df.set_index('proj_id')
proj_df['cust_part_total_trans'] = merge['proj_id'].value_counts()
proj_df['cust_part_total_trans'] = proj_df['cust_part_total_trans'].replace(np.NaN, 0).astype(int)

proj_df = proj_df.reset_index()
merge = pd.merge(proj_df, transaction_df, on=['cust_name', 'part_no', 'partner'])
merge = merge[merge['last_purchase_date']>=merge['transaction_date']]
#setting index is necessary for value_counts() to match correctly
proj_df = proj_df.set_index('proj_id')
proj_df['cust_part_partner_total_trans'] = merge['proj_id'].value_counts()
proj_df['cust_part_partner_total_trans'] = proj_df['cust_part_partner_total_trans'].replace(np.NaN, 0).astype(int)
proj_df.sort_index()
```

As you can see the code is very similar for all three tasks. We just add more keys to the merge/join keys to account for the "for each X, Y, Z".

Since the merge gives us the date we can just filter to only keep the dates which match our condition.

Comment: Hi, just checking this. Appreciate your effort. I don't think it matches the expected output though

Comment: Is it because you are taking value_counts of proj_id?

Comment: It matches the description that you have given. With how you describe the columns you want to add, I think your expected output is still wrong and mine appears correct as far as I can tell

Comment: 'merge['proj_id'].value_counts()', can I know why proj id is counted to get value for 'cust_part_total_trans'?  Aren't we expected to count based on total transactions count based on matching customer and part

Comment: You can look at the `merge` dataframe to better understand that. For the following I'll be referring to the first `merge` (merge only on `cust_name`). Each row corresponds to a match between `proj_df` and `transaction_df`. We can see 5 rows in `merge` which have `proj_id=1`. That means we have 5 transactions (since each of these rows correspond to a unique transaction in `transaction_df`) for that project. Using `value_counts` on `proj_id` allows us to count the number of occurrences (i.e. transactions) for each value (i. e. for each project).